# Change in apple metal kernel does not change execution time

Tags: gpgpu, metal

I modified the kernel code in the above project
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/basic_tasks_and_concepts/performing_calculations_on_a_gpu?preferredLanguage=occ

from this

```cpp
kernel void add_arrays(device const float* inA,
                       device const float* inB,
                       device float* result,
                       uint index [[thread_position_in_grid]])
{
    // the for-loop is replaced with a collection of threads, each of which
    // calls this function.
     result[index] = inA[index] + inB[index] ;
    
}
```

to this just embedding same calculation inside a for loop

```cpp
kernel void add_arrays(device const float* inA,
                       device const float* inB,
                       device float* result,
                       uint index [[thread_position_in_grid]])
{
    // the for-loop is replaced with a collection of threads, each of which
    // calls this function.
    for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++){ // added
        result[index] = inA[index] + inB[index] ;
    }
}
```

but the execution time of the program does not change , am I doing something wrong

Comment: I guess the compiler recocognizes that you are doing the same instruction on every loop run and optimizes the code by removing the loop. Try doing something with `i` inside the loop and see if this affects the performance.

Answer (score 1):

as @frank-schlegel suggested I firstly added

```cpp
for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++){
        result[index] = inA[index] + inB[index] + i;
}
```

it did not change the performance
but when I added below code

```cpp
for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++){
        result[index] +=  i;
}
```

It significantly did,
My conclusion is Metal compiler probably optimizes code super intelligently!